# Finding a likelihood function given binary observed data

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, solution-verification

I'm having trouble really understanding the terms used for this homework question, and what I am actually supposed to be doing, given the actual data for the problem. Below is the problem:

Suppose we observe a random sample $(X_1,...,X_n)$ with $n = 10$, where $X_i \sim Bernoulli(p)$ and $p$ is the proportion of black cars at school. Suppose we observed $(x_1,...,x_{10}) = (1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0)$.

a. Find the likelihood function $L(p)$ given the ten binary observations.

b. Find the log-likelihood function $l(p) = logL(p)$.

c. Take the first derivative of $l(p)$ with respect to $p$.

d. Report the estimate of the population proportion of black cars based on the method of maximum likelihood estimation.

---

My answers:

a. $L(p) = \prod_{i = 1}^{10} P(X_i | p) = (p^{x_1} \times (1 - p)^{10 - x_1}) \times ...  \times (p^{x_{10}} \times (1-p)^{10 - x_{10}}) = p^r \times (1 - p)^{n - r}$ where $r$ is the number of black vehicles and $(n - r)$ is the number of non-black vehicles.

b. $l(p) = logL(p) = rlog(p) + (n-r)log(1 - p)$

c. For this I know eventually I have to set it to $0$ and solve to get the maximum likelihood estimation, but for now is this all I have to do?

$l(p)(\frac{d}{dp}) = \frac{r}{p} - \frac{n-r}{1-p}$

d. For d, I feel like I'm doing something wrong since it can't be this easy.. but first I set the derivative to $0$, $\frac{r}{p} - \frac{n-r}{1-p} = 0$

I end up getting $\hat{p} = \frac{r}{n}$ where $r = \sum^{10}_{i = 1}X_i = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 4$

So I plug that in and get $\hat{p} = \frac{4}{10} = 0.4$

Would this be correct?

Comment: Strictly speaking for (d) you may need to show this gives a maximum rather than a minimum or something else, but otherwise this looks both correct and intuitive